# Authenticate different users in ldap present in different ou

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, active-directory, ldap

Consider that I have two users ,user1 and user2 are under the following base_dc respectively

:base_dc:ou="ABC",ou="DEF",DC="XXX"
:base_dc:ou="HIJ",ou="POQ",DC="XXX"

Now my question is , while logging into the application I would be taking the username and password and used to have the above (any 1) configuration  in my config/ldap_config.yml file and used to authenticate. Now that there are 2 different users in different OU , I am finding it bit difficult as how to write a single base_dc so that ldap can search the user in the active directory and authenticate. As of now there are no additional parameters associated with the users like phoneNumber and stuff.

So can anyone suggest what might be the solution ? Or how should I handle this situation ?
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

If your DC=XXX means that both the users are in the same domain, set your search base to dc=XXX.

Where you run into trouble is when you have two non-overlapping base DN's.

Comment: ok thanks that did worked for me.But can you tell me how can I set search privilege to a particular user and non of other users must search the AD.Its something like that guy has admin privileges .

Comment: @karthik339 Usually what you do is your service binds as one account, that has sufficient rights, does a search for uid=jsmith or maybe mail=jsmith@acme.com or even sn=Smith, and then once you get a response, you find their full DN, then bind as their full DN, and the supplied password (or else passwordCompare, bind is nicer as it touches login time attrs if supported) to see if they are allowed access.